# data-mapper not found on mule ee 3.3.0

Tags: datamapper, mule

I'm implementing a project using the mule ee 3.3.0 and I want to use the data-mapper. For your information, I do not work with the MuleStudio. I am working with an actual eclipse and the Mule IDE plugin.
Everything works, but I can not use the new data-mapper feature. I did not find any data-mapper package on the Mule Libraries ( mule-enterprise-standalone-3.3.0 ) and there is also no schema definition file on the your website ( should be something like this http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/e... ).

Do I miss something?

PS: I posted this question also at the MuleSoft forum, but I'm eager to get this problem solved:
[original post](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/data_mapper_not_found_on_mule_ee_3_3_0)

Comment: Problem is: this concerns the Enterprise Edition of Mule, which is better supported by MuleSoft Enterprise Support directly instead of community forums.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.3 MuleStudio debuted, however still without DataMapper.
It wasn't until 3.4 that DataMapper was released.